# .net core api does not accept postman post request body

Tags: c#, api, post, .net-core, postman

I created an api in .net core 3.1, and I'm testing some requests with Postman.

I created a categorydto.cs class and added some date annotations, but even though I pass in the correct information, postman returns me as invalid.

```
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Description{ get; private set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Observable is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Observable{ get; private set; }
            
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] DTOs.CategotyDTO categoryDTO)
{
    var category = new Category(categoryDTO.Description, categoryDTO.Obervable);
    
    if (category == null)
    {
       return BadRequest("Category é null");
    }
                
    _categoryRepository.Save(category);
    
    return Ok();
}
```

in post man i have a
POST, raw JSON

```
{
    "Description": "Category 1",
    "Observable": "Observable 1",
}
```

and the return of the api is

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|c4215190-4f62962a8efd326f.",
    "errors": {
        "Description": [
            "Description is required"
        ],
        "Observable": [
            "Observable is required"
        ]
    }
}
```

I've already disabled postman's ssl, but even so the information doesn't reach my api, I have to do some configuration for my api to accept the json what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the private keyword from the set property in Category DTO class.I just did that and your code worked

```
public class CategoryDTO
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Description { get;  set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Observable is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Observable { get;  set; }

    }
```

[image]